# How to display spinner and listview in a class that extends fragment

Tags: android

I'm new to android I had declared a class that extends fragment class. In that class I declared the spinner and a list view. While running the code I can see the spinner and the list but in they list I'm unable to see the value

Answer (score 0):

Extends FragmentActivity instead of Fragment...